# What is the best way to import SQL table data in SharePoint 2010 list?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I have a SQL server table with data. And I want to import this data in SharePoint 2010 list.

What will be the best to import this data into my SharePoint 2010 list?.

That should be useful during the deployment into the production which can be use by my client easily.

Please suggest me the different ways and how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SQL Server Integration Services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx
2. Write a program to read the SQL Server tables and write to SharePoint using one of the object models, for example, a C# program that uses the SharePoint server object model to write to the list.

If you export your SQL Server table to Execl, then you have these additional options:

1. Import from Excel: In SharePoint: Create, List, Import SpreadSheet.
2. Export from Excel: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-an-excel-table-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA010131472.aspx
3. Paste from Excel into Datasheet view of existing SharePoint list: copy rows in Excel; switch to SharePoint to a datasheet view (with at least the mandatory fields); order the datasheet the same as your Excel columns; and then righ-click the first cell and select Paste.

Comment: Thanks to reply.. i used the asp.net application to insert the share point list item.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me :

1. Export sql server table as excel.
2. Create a sharepoint list view keeping the columns order same as excel.
3. Copy the rows into datsheet view and save..